# Prevenir el ingreso del keyCode = 222 y keyCode = 186

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy restringiendo el ingreso de ciertos caracteres a un `input type="text"`, necesito que solo se puedan ingresar números, lo tengo casi listo pero el único problema es que no puedo prevenir que los caracteres de las teclas de keyCode == 222 y 186 se ingresen, son las que en el teclado español tipean los caracteres ` y ´ respectivamente.

El código:

```
$("#myInput").keydown(function(e){
  if (((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) && ((e.keyCode < 13 || e.keyCode > 13) && (e.keyCode < 8 || e.keyCode > 9))) && ((e.keyCode < 37 || e.keyCode > 37) && (e.keyCode < 39 || e.keyCode > 39)) || e.keyCode == 222 || e.keyCode == 186) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Si corren el cursor hacia la derecha, en la parte final del if estoy intentando restringir los keyCodes 222 y 186, pero no funciona, me he cabeceado demasiado en ese `if`, pero no lo logro.

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo prevenir que se ingresen los caracteres de esas teclas?

Por cierto, sé que existe el `input type="number"` pero para este proyecto específico, no me sirve.

**EDIT**

Recién noté que esas teclas si las apretas una vez, no lanzan el caracter, pero si las apretas dos veces, lanzarán el caracter **``** o **´´** así, dos veces. Entonces deduzco que es algún problema con el keydown, de ser así, ¿qué podría usar sin perder la funcionalidad que ya tengo?

> PD: además de dejar pasar números, también dejo pasar el intro, el tab, backspace, flechas izquierda y derecha pues los necesito.

Comment: Rodrigo, puedes hacer un `alert(e.keyCode)`

Comment: sí, si lo pongo antes del e.preventDefault(); e ingreso una tecla distinta a un número, me muestra efectivamente el keyCode, también lo hace cuando presiono un ` o un ´  pero lo raro es que sí inserta ese caracter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Interceptar acentos españoles

El problema es que esas teclas se interpretan como acentos, al presionarlas dos veces el keypress lo manda como tecla pero el keydown no lo detecta (probado en Chrome con Win10). Para capturar esas teclas hay que combinar los eventos keydown y keypress. Hay que capturar las teclas en ambos eventos

### Ejemplo

Poniendo esto en un archivo.html se puede probar, en el primer input hay que tipear, en el segundo se ven los códigos, que no coinciden entre keypress y keydown:

```
<input id=uno>
<input id=dos>
<script>
function stopNonNum(e){
  dos.value=e.keyCode+'/'+e.shiftKey;
  if(((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) 
      && ((e.keyCode < 13 || e.keyCode > 13) && (e.keyCode < 8 || e.keyCode > 9))) 
      && ((e.keyCode < 37 || e.keyCode > 37)) || e.keyCode == 222 || e.keyCode == 186 || e.keyCode == 96) 
  {
    dos.value=dos.value+'-';
    e.preventDefault();
  }else{
    dos.value=dos.value+'+';
  }
}
uno.onkeydown=stopNonNum;  
uno.onkeypress=stopNonNum;  
</script>
```

Comment: te refieres a algo como: $("#myInput").on("keydown keypress",function(e){...?

Comment: ahí puse un ejemplo que se puede ejecutar directamente dentro de un .html

Comment: Maravilloso muchas gracias!